# How to auto update a userstyle

Tags: browser, browser-addons, greasemonkey

I currently make and update a *Stylish* userstyle and it is updated frequently, is there any way that I can add to the userstyle to make it auto update for people who use it?
Or if I can't do the above, can I make a *Greasemonkey* script to do so?

Comment: Judging by your suggested edit it appears you have either lost your identifying cookie (needed for unregistered accounts) or you are using a different computer or browser.  If you [register an account](https://superuser.com/users/signup) from your original computer you'll then be able to edit, comment on and accept answers to this question.  If you no longer have access to that machine/browser you can register a new account and then use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) to request your old and new accounts to be merged which will give you control of this question.

Answer (score 1):

#### I need a greasemonkey/stylish script that can auto update

Greasemonkey scripts can already auto update (since 2012)

There is an active [discussion](https://blog.userstyles.org/discussion/1444/request-auto-update-for-stylish-user-styles) (last update 2014) regarding adding auto update to stylish scripts. The last applicable comment would seem to "No plans to have automatic updates" (2009).

---

#### Automatic script updates come to Greasemonkey

> In the 0.9.18 release, Greasemonkey is now checking for, and
>   installing, updated versions of user scripts by default.  This post is
>   intended as a primer for how this new functionality works, both for
>   users and for script authors.
>
> [image]
>
> The Greasemonkey Options dialog now includes these settings to control
>   automatic update checking and installation. By default updates will be
>   checked for every seven days, and automatically installed when found. 
>   The download location must be secure (https) by default.  And it
>   should just work!
>
> If you know there's an update, you can open the Add-ons manager, right
>   click on a User Script, and choose "Find Updates".  This will check
>   immediately, even if a scheduled check has happened more recently than
>   seven days ago.*
>
> *You may need to clear your browser cache, if an old version of the script was downloaded recently.
>
> **Script Authors**
>
> Greasemonkey supports a number of new metadata directives to support
>   updates: @downloadURL, @updateURL and (more than before) @version.
>
> The @updateURL will be accessed when checking for the update.  This
>   can be a ".meta.js" format like userscripts.org produces, with only
>   the metadata.  The @version defined here will be checked to the
>   install version.  It does not need to be hosted on https to be checked
>   by default.
>
> Sidebar: for userscripts.org, the updateURL is automatically set to
>   the .meta.js corresponding to the script, and passed through the Coral
>   Content Distribution Network (see why).
>
> The @downloadURL is where the update will be downloaded from, when
>   found.  This is most useful to guarantee that updates come from a
>   secure (https) location, so that they will be installed by default.
>
> If @updateURL or @downloadURL are not provided, the URL that the
>   script was downloaded from is used instead.  If the @downloadURL is
>   not provided and the install URL is not known, updates will never be
>   applied.
>
> Finally the @version directive controls what is considered an update. 
>   Read about the (Mozilla) toolkit version format to learn exactly what
>   value is greater than what, and what formats are valid.
>
> It's also worth pointing out that the recently added GM_info API can
>   be used to check if Greasemonkey will ever try to apply updates (e.g.
>   because the user has turned it off, or the URL is insecure).
>
> Finally, if you want to make sure that Greasemonkey will never update
>   your script, it can be accomplished by providing an invalid @updateURL
>   (like "about:blank") which will never return a newer version.

Source [Automatic script updates come to Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/2012/02/automatic-script-updates-come-to.html)